# Format a date retrieved from xml file using jstl

Tags: jsp, xml-parsing, jstl

i have an XML file that contains

```
<DT>
<date>2014-02-01T12:00:00</date>
</DT>
```

then i retrive the date with JSTL XML parser

```
<c:import url="dtdict.xml" var="dtdict_dem" charEncoding="UTF-8"/>
<x:parse doc="${dtdict_dem}" var="dossier"/>
       <c:set scope="request" var="date">
<x:out select="$dossier/DT/date" />
</c:set>
```

then i use formatDate to format the date

```
<fmt:formatDate var="fmt_date" value="${date}"pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
        <label>Date  :</label><label> ${fmt_date} </label>
```

but when i run i receive this error

```
javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert 2014-02-01T12:00:00 of type class java.lang.String to class java.util.Date
```

help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse the date String first.

```
<fmt:parseDate value="${date}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" var="myDate"/>
<fmt:formatDate var="fmt_date" value="${myDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <label>Date  :</label><label> ${fmt_date} </label>
```